# gcloud deploy error - handlers in YAML file

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml, gcloud

We're getting the following error when deploying our Python App to GCP App Engine; This is the error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2022-10-18T20:09:37.332Z36906.wa.2: [2022-10-18 20:09:41 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0

This is the YAML configuration:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

resources:
  cpu: 0.5
  memory_gb: 0.90
  disk_size_gb: 10

manual_scaling:
    instances: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  script: auto
  secure: always
    
entrypoint: gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py -b :$PORT "wsgi:app"

service: dev-extract-test
```

Comment: You should be able to find a more informative error message in your logs.

Answer (score 0):

The error was pointing to a Module that was accidentally included by Visual Code. The import statement was removed and the code was successfully deployed to GCP App Engine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).